# C# - Insert data to multiple tables to database with business logic using Business layer or Data Access Layer (DAL)?

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I have the ASP.NET web application which is based on 3 tiers architecture. (Presentation, Business, and Data Access Layer).

I am going to develop the function which inserts the new client records. Based on Business rules, the new client record must contain the client information, guardian information, and client log history (client created date and client activation date).

When inserting a new client record to the database, I need the insert to write any related records to database as well (i.e, guardian records and log history records based on 1 to many relationship database design).

Under DAL, I already created functions: `InsertClientRecord`, `InsertClientGuardian`, and `InsertClientLogHistory` function.

I want to create a main function which calls `InsertClientMain` which contains orderly step:

1. `InsertClientRecord (ClientRecords);`
2. `InsertClientGuardian (ClientGuardian);`
3. `InsertClientLogHistory ("Client is created");`
4. `InsertClientLogHistory ("Client is activated");`

Since `InsertClientMain` contains Business rules (insert client log history), should I create this function under Business Layer or DAL?

Also, I want to wrap the transaction scope in the `InsertClientMain` function. If the `InsertClientMain` is in the Business Layer, can I use the transaction scope in the Business Layer? I read an article that Business layer must not use anything related to database transaction or persistence (DAL should handle all the database things).

Thank you

Comment: In data access abstraction you can create method `ExecuteInTransaction` which takes an `Action` as parameter. So `Action` will represent your business logic and `ExecuteInTransaction` will wrap it with `TransactionScope`. You can still test your business logic without dependencies on data access implementation.

Comment: Don't make yourself get stuck with questions like `where should be the appropriate place of the code logic`. If your code base is loosely-coupled enough (by abstracting BLL and DAL), you can replace them later on using other implementation. Btw, BLL is sometimes just a pass-through layer but sometimes a BL method can be a mixup of underlying DA method and other BL methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Fabio and Bod Dust